# Is there a size constraint to consider to make sure that the LAME tag is valid?

Tags: mp3, lame

I want to manipulate the MP3 Xing/Info/LAME tags.

I found [some documentation](http://gabriel.mp3-tech.org/mp3infotag.html) which has various definitions, but it does not really mention that one piece of information: how do you determine that the tag is indeed valid?

I'm asking because I created VBR and CBR audio files and the LAME tag seems to appear in all the frames that have space not used by audio sample data. But in most cases the space available is going to be too small for the complete tag.

So, is the tag always considered valid, but we have to pay attention to the size and ignore any field which is after the end of the buffer? Or should I make sure the whole tag (208 bytes?) is present and if not completely ignore the tag?

What do existing MP3 players do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I actually noticed some discrepancy in the *documentation* I linked to and thought I'd better search directly in LAME to see how it's done there.

Sure enough, the *documentation* is completely off in many different ways. However, what I find interesting is that the LAME implementation does not check to know whether the buffer is large enough. At least the `GetVbrTag()` function itself only verifies that the input data is a Layer III frame. So the frame could be smaller than is required by the tag (I would think it can.) It could be that the function only gets called in situations where it will actually work as expected.

Anyway, as the code is written, it assumes that all the expected data is present. It reads increasing the `buf` pointer along and reading data until it's all done.

Source: If you have the LAME project source code, see `libmp3lame/VbrTag.c` at line 362 (in version 3.100 of LAME) for the function I'm talking about.